how to call a procedure only after complete data gets ingested
querydatabasetable --> fetch data from source approx 1GB data.
convertavrotojson ---> converting avro fromat data to json format.
splitjson --> splitting a json flowfile into single json record/row.
evaluatejsonpath --> mapping the attributes.
replacetext --> preparing insert statement and making some transformations to the data using regex expressions.
putsql--> ingesting all the data into postgresql. I'm not holding any data in the success relationship of putsql, using flowfile expiration as 2 sec. I'm emptying the queue. as the records count is huge
as the queue threshold is 10,000. i have given flowfile expiration for 2 seconds for the success of putsql.
so after all the data is ingested and flowfile gets empty after expiration i need to trigger the next executesql processor to run stored procedures.
so how to trigger next processor after putsql processor. Here, I'm splitting the json file to single json record to perform some transformations on data. so using merge content in defragmentation strategy and merge format as zip doesn't work. and i cant hold data for too long after putsql, because the queues will be on hold when it reaches the threshold size.
So, how to trigger executesql processor only once after all the records got ingested. can you please help me in creating this flow.
i used rest api to check queue size whether less than 0 or greater than 0. if less than 0 then only it calls stored procedure. but how to trigger invokehttp (rest api) or executesql to call procedure only after ingestion is completed.


option 1
querydbtable populates attribute querydbtable.row.count.
why not to pass this parameter to a sproc call - so, it could check if number of rows in source table corresponds to number of rows in a staging table.
in this case you will call sproc every time but it could take a decision if data is ready to be processed
option 2
querydbtable populates fragment.* attributes that could be useful for MergeContent.
You can merge jsons into array of jsons. when merge is completed - you can call sproc or api...
parameters to join into a json array:
Merge Strategy: Defragment
Delimiter Strategy: Text
Header: [
Footer: ]
Demarcator: ,

Actually, there is no need to build json array in your case. So, header/footer parameters are optional.
MergeContent will wait for all fragments, so it will act as a trigger that all small jsons were processed.

how to merge jsons into array of jsons using merge content. can you help me on this @daggett

after putsql, I'm using 2 other executesql processors. one processor which oracle connection and the other executesql processor with postgresql connection. and using queries like select count () as oracle_count from source_table ; and select count () as postgres_count from postgres_table. if count matches then only calling the procedure. i have added these to the flow. but how to trigger executesql to take counts after ingestion is completed. how will executesql processor will get to know using option1. can you elaborate and explain me on creating the flow @dagget

how to know the number of rows in a staging table. through fragment.* attributes can we get to know ? or through other attributes can we know the count of rows got ingested into staging table. because after complete ingestion is completed, after that only once the procedure call should be called without hitting DB more times. @daggett

QueryDatabaseTable writes an attribute querydbtable.row.count - The number of rows selected by the query. if you are not setting Max Rows Per Flow File then you have one file after query and fragment.* attributes are not populated. But SplitJson will write fragment.* according to the number of records in a file. So, mergecontent with defragment should work for you.  Look at Writes Attributes section in processors that you are using https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.26.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html
